# Asp.net custom control and javascript function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, custom-controls

There's a custom a asp.net control named PhoneTextBox2. It uses ext.net library, but I doesn't matter.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="PhoneTextBox2.ascx.cs"
    Inherits="Loginet.Web.Controls.PhoneTextBox2" %>

 <script type="text/javascript">
               var <%=ClientID%>_getNumber = function () {
                return alert( 'some value');
            }
        </script>
<ext:CompositeField runat="server" ID="eCompositeField">
        <Items>
            <ext:Label ID="PhoneBoxTitle" runat="server" />
        </Items>
</ext:CompositeField>
```

In aspx page I call the javascript method of `PhoneTextBox2` by this way

```
<uc:PhoneTextBox2 runat="server" ID="txtb" />
<ext:Button Text="test" runat="server">
        <Listeners>
            <Click Handler="#{txtb}_getNumber();"></Click>
        </Listeners>
</ext:Button>
```

`#{txtb}_getNumber()` is the unique name of the javascript function, and `#{txtb}` - is the unique name of the `PhoneTextBox2`.

What can I do to call getNumber by **dot**?

```
<Click Handler="#{txtb}.getNumber();">
```

UPDATE:

```
    public partial class PhoneTextBox2 : System.Web.UI.UserControl {
            /// <summary>
            /// Допускаются ли, чтобы все поля были пустыми
            /// True - Допускаются. Используется тогда, когда данные из этого контрола необязательные.
            /// </summary>
            public bool EnableEmptyValues { get; set; }
            public string Title { get; set; }
            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

                txtCountryCode.AllowBlank = EnableEmptyValues;
                txtCityCode.AllowBlank = EnableEmptyValues;
                txtMainPhoneNumber.AllowBlank = EnableEmptyValues;

                if (!IsPostBack && !Ext.Net.ExtNet.IsAjaxRequest) {
                    PhoneBoxTitle.Text = Title;
                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DataSource)) {

                        string[] phoneNumberArray = DataSource.Split('-');
                        if (phoneNumberArray.Length >= _standartDimension) {
                            txtCountryCode.Text = phoneNumberArray[0];
                            if (txtCountryCode.Text[0] == _plus) {
                                txtCountryCode.Text = txtCountryCode.Text.Remove(0, 1);
                            }
                            txtCityCode.Text = phoneNumberArray[1];
                            txtMainPhoneNumber.Text = phoneNumberArray[2];
                            if (phoneNumberArray.Length >= _extraDimension) {
                                txtExtraPhoneNumber.Text = phoneNumberArray[3];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }


            public string DataSource { get; set; }


            private const string _phoneNumberMask = "+{0}-{1}-{2}-{3}";
            private const char _plus = '+';
            private const int _standartDimension = 3;
            private const int _extraDimension = 4;

            public string Number {
                get {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtCountryCode.Text) &&
                        !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtCityCode.Text) &&
                        !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtMainPhoneNumber.Text)) {

                        //Если добавочный номер пустой, то возвратить значения без него
                        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtExtraPhoneNumber.Text))
                            return string.Format(_phoneNumberMask, txtCountryCode.Text, txtCityCode.Text, txtMainPhoneNumber.Text, txtExtraPhoneNumber.Text);

                        string phoneNumber = string.Format(_phoneNumberMask, txtCountryCode.Text, txtCityCode.Text, txtMainPhoneNumber.Text, string.Empty);
                        return phoneNumber.Remove(phoneNumber.Length - 1);

                    }
                    return string.Empty;
                }
            }


            public bool IsEmpty {
                get {
                    return (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtCountryCode.Text) &&
                            string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtCityCode.Text) &&
                            string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtMainPhoneNumber.Text) &&
                            string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtMainPhoneNumber.Text));
                }
            }




            /// <summary>
            /// Validate 
            /// </summary>
            public void Validate() {
                if (EnableEmptyValues) {
                    if (!IsEmpty && Number == string.Empty)
                        MarkInvalid();
                    else
                        MarkValid();
                }

                else {
                    if (IsEmpty)
                        MarkInvalid();
                    else {
                        if (Number == string.Empty)
                            MarkInvalid();
                        else
                            MarkValid();
                    }
                }
            }

            public void MarkInvalid(string msg = null) {
                txtCountryCode.MarkInvalid(msg);
                txtCityCode.MarkInvalid(msg);
                txtMainPhoneNumber.MarkInvalid(msg);
                txtExtraPhoneNumber.MarkInvalid(msg);

            }

            public void MarkValid() {
                txtCountryCode.MarkAsValid();
                txtCityCode.MarkAsValid();
                txtMainPhoneNumber.MarkAsValid();
                txtExtraPhoneNumber.MarkAsValid();
            }


             public const string InvalidCheckBoxCssStyle = "border-color:#C30; background:  url('/extjs/resources/images/default/grid/invalid_line-gif/ext.axd') repeat-x scroll center bottom white; width: 40px !important;";
         public const string ValidCheckBoxCssStyle = "border-color:#000; background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;";
}
```

Note, in **my case** I can't use the server side property `Number` because of feature of ext.net. Therefore I need to use javascript to get `Number`.

Answer (score 0):

`Handler` points to a .NET custom method/delegate, and they can't have period signs in their names.

---

You can extend any object type, for example:

```
String.prototype.getNumber = function() { 
  alert('here: ' + this);
};
```

and then

```
'txtElement'.getNumber();
```

so you can change your code to

```
<Click Handler="'{txtb}'.getNumber();">
```

Comment: Handler points to a custom **javascript** function or standart ext.net **javascript** function.

Comment: has to have some code behind, I dont get why the hash sign `#` there... :-/

Comment: #{txtb} is used in ext.net. It's the same as <%=txtb.ClientID%>

Comment: Can I extend the PhoneTextBox2? It's something like this `PhoneTextBox2.prototype.getNumber = function() { 
  alert('here: ' + this);
};`

Comment: when extending prototype you just need to place the code once, normally in a javascript file called `plugin.js` that, is called in the master page. I can see that you don't know what my code does ... unless you can point to the control source code, I can't be to much of a help.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to assign a dynamic name to your javascript function. Simply register the method when the first control is created, and check to see if it's already registered when the next instance of the control is created.

Registering a script block:

```
if (!Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("getNumberScript"))
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "getNumberScript", "getNumber = function () { return alert( 'some value'); }", true);
```

Registering an include file (external js):

```
if (!Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptIncludeRegistered("getNumberScript"))
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("getNumberScript", "getNumberScript.js");
```